# ASP.NET Event Handler for Image Button not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, imagebutton

I am just trying to add `onClick` event to dynamically created `ImageButton`, and it should be easy, but for some reason, my click event is not firing, no matter what I do.

I created a couple of image buttons and add them to the table.

Here is my code for that bit:

```
TableCell cell= new TableCell();
ImageButton pic= new ImageButton();
pic.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(pic_Click);
pic.ImageUrl = "~/Pictures/" + list[j];
pic.Width = 180;
pic.Height = 150;
pic.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Inset;
pic.BorderColor = Color.DarkRed;
cell.Controls.Add(pic);
row.Cells.Add(cell);
```

and my method look like this :

```
public void pic_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e) 
{
    //codehere
}
```

and it just doesn't work, image buttons are created and added to the table as planned, but `OnClick` is just not doing it's job..  I also tried adding event like this :

```
pic.Click += pic_Click;
```

but it's the same. Just to say, I am not doing this in `Page_Load` method.

Comment: Can you verify you are actually firing a click event? Can you use this same event binding successfully on a static element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take care of you dynamic controls during the PreInit event of the Page, as it says [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#lifecycle_events).

You mentioned you're not doing it in the Page_Load, I assume you're doing it at a later point. If you follow the guideline above, your button's click event handler will run.

Comment: if you can help me just a little bit more, i read the link you've sent me, but i don't quite understand what it is i am supposed to do? All my dynamic controls are created depending of what user chooses, how can i re-create them in PreInit event ?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't follow this format? 
.aspx

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" Height="100px" ImageUrl="~/Images2/addtocartbutton.jpg" Width="250px" OnClick="ImageButton1_Click" />
```

.aspx.cs

```
protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{

}
```